# Flatten only one Enum variant

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to flatten an Enum, conditionally.

For example, I could receive whether a "TextBody" or "HtmlBody" (or both!) field in a JSON message.

```json
{
  "Field1": ... ,
  "TextBody": "some text",
  "HtmlBody": "<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"
  "Field4": ... ,
}
```

So I'd like to represent this as:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Body {
    #[serde(rename = "TextBody")]
    Text(String),
    #[serde(rename = "HtmlBody")]
    Html(String),
    #[serde(flatten)]
    HtmlAndText(HtmlAndText),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct HtmlAndText {
    #[serde(rename = "HtmlBody")]
    pub html: String,
    #[serde(rename = "TextBody")]
    pub text: String,
}
```

However, the `#[serde(flatten)]` cannot be applied to an individual element of an Enum. It could be applied to the fields of the struct `HtmlAndText` but those fields are simply String themselves, and don't need flattening.

Without flattening, I would get JSON that looks like

```json
{
  "Field1": ... ,
  "Body": {
    "TextBody": "some text",
    "HtmlBody": "<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"
  },
  "Field4": ... ,
}
```

How can make an enum to represent serializing/deserializing either or both of an HtmlBody and TextBody field?

Comment: Why don't have just `Option<String>` for both?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is three enum variants with named fields:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Body {
    // This variant must come first!
    // Otherwise it will just stop when the text variant is matched
    HtmlAndText {
        #[serde(rename = "TextBody")]
        text: String,
        #[serde(rename = "HtmlBody")]
        html: String,
    },
    Text {
        #[serde(rename = "TextBody")]
        text: String,
    },
    Html {
        #[serde(rename = "HtmlBody")]
        html: String,
    },
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9dcc65201aaf7f0a1fd59cdc92e42a0)

Comment: That's way more complicated than necessary, as Chayim Friedman notes above you can just have `text` and `html` as `Option<String>`, and optionally add a `skip_serializing_if` if you want to skip these fields during serialization when they're empty (unset): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cee3145093efb3a9e88373b2c9856093 only drawback is that allows having neither, and that doesn't seem like much of an issue.

Comment: I think "way more complicated" is a bit of an exaggeration, but I agree that just having two `Option<String>`s is a better approach, despite needing more explicit logic.